# redirect all request to https://www symfony2 google HTTP load balancer

Tags: symfony, redirect, https, google-cloud-platform

I know this question has been asked so many times earlier but I tried every solutions and none is not working for me .

I am using symfony2 with google cloud hosting and using their http load balancer. My `.htaccess` has following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

My load balancer have 2 forwarding rules, one for http and one for https.

Now, I can redirect all requests to https://www.example.com, but I am still unable to redirect http://www.example.com to the HTTPS url.

Please let me know where I am getting it wrong, I was using AWS and rackspace earlier and never faced same issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to solve it by following method , I know it is not the best one so suggestions are still invited.

I added following code in app.php

```
 if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'http' &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.example.com') {
 header("Location: https://www.example.com".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
#add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

The condition above

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
```

checks if the orignal scheme is http, redirect it to https.

Comment: Sorry mate , still the same

Comment: 301 is a permanent redirect, browsers remember it forever,so you need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: I did it , still the same :(